# Avoid the limit of 10 pool connections

Tags: node.js

I have the problem of when I make 10 pool connections, it stops working. I put here my api code, where I make `app.get` and with it I have to do a database query.

Any suggestion?

```
app.get('/test', function(req, resp){
pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    const query = client.query('SELECT * FROM mytable;',  (err, res) => {
        resp.json(res.rows);
    });      
});
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're not releasing your connection.  eg: `client.release()` after the resp.json line.

Comment: Thank you so much generalhenry. It worked. Thanks